# Follow an average cycloid results in turtle type error

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to have each dot follow their equivalent centroid which is the average of 3 different dots. But when I set up with 7 dots (number == 7) I only see 3 centroids instead, etc. The number of centroids does not match the number of dots and when I press go i get this error message:

```
error while dot 4 running CENTROID
  called by procedure MOVE-DOTS
  called by procedure GO
  called by Button 'go'
```

And as an observer I type centroid 0 and it also throws and error message. What should I be fixing to make it work? I created (number) centroids so i feel like it should be the same number of dots. And the meanx and meany logic seems to make sense to me. if it is dot 0 it will do dots 1 to 3 and because there is no negative who number dots it will just do those. (the or part is to account for those whose who number is too high it requires it to wrap around to 0)

```
globals [number2]
breed [centroids centroid]
breed [dots dot]

to setup
  clear-all
  setup-patches
  setup-dots
  set-default-shape centroids "x"
  setup-centroid
  reset-ticks
end

to setup-patches
  ask patches [ set pcolor green ]
end

to setup-dots
  create-dots number    ;; uses the value of the number slider to create dots
  set number2 (number)
  ask dots [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor ]
end

to go
  ifelse number2 = number              ;check if user changed number
  [
    move-dots
    move-centroid
    tick-advance 1                     ;; increment the tick counter]
  ]
  [setup]

end

to move-dots
  ask dots [
    face centroid who
    forward (distance centroid who) / (ticks/sec * number ) ; divide by number is alpha = 1/N for stability
  ]
end

; add a dot that shows center of formation/mass
to setup-centroid
  create-centroids (number)
  move-centroid 
end

to move-centroid
  ask centroids[
    
    let meanx (mean ([xcor] of (dots with [(who > [who] of myself and who <= (([who] of myself) + 3)) or (who <= (([who] of myself) - (number - 4)))] )))
     let meany   (mean ([ycor] of (dots with [(who > [who] of myself and who <= (([who] of myself) + 3)) or (who <= (([who] of myself) - (number - 4)))] )))
    
      setxy meanx meany
  ]
end
```

The error I get is this (for number equals 5 but the dot number changes in the error statement (ex it sometimes says 'dot 4 is not a CENTROID' or 'dot 0 is not a CENTROID')

````
error while dot 2 running CENTROID
  called by procedure MOVE-DOTS
  called by procedure GO
  called by Button 'go'

org.nlogo.nvm.RuntimePrimitiveException: dot 2 is not a CENTROID
 at org.nlogo.prim._asm_proceduremovedots_face_1.perform(:2)
 at org.nlogo.nvm.Context.runExclusive(Context.java:133)
 at org.nlogo.nvm.ExclusiveJob.run(ExclusiveJob.scala:39)
 at org.nlogo.nvm.Context.runExclusiveJob(Context.java:177)
 at org.nlogo.prim._asm_proceduremovedots_ask_0.perform(:1)
 at org.nlogo.nvm.Context.stepConcurrent(Context.java:107)
 at org.nlogo.nvm.ConcurrentJob.step(ConcurrentJob.scala:65)
 at org.nlogo.job.JobThread.runPrimaryJobs(JobThread.scala:133)
 at org.nlogo.job.JobThread.$anonfun$run$1(JobThread.scala:68)
 at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
 at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:228)
 at org.nlogo.api.Exceptions$.handling(Exceptions.scala:41)
 at org.nlogo.job.JobThread.run(JobThread.scala:66)

NetLogo 6.2.0
main: org.nlogo.app.AppFrame
thread: JobThread
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 1.8.0_275 (BellSoft; 1.8.0_275-b01)
operating system: Windows 10 10.0 (amd64 processor)
Scala version 2.12.12
JOGL: (3D View not initialized)
OpenGL Graphics: (3D View not initialized)
model: Cyclic Group

07:11:49.060 RuntimeErrorEvent (org.nlogo.app.App$$anon$4 (org.nlogo.window.GUIWorkspace)) AWT-EventQueue-0
07:11:49.047 AddJobEvent (org.nlogo.window.ButtonWidget) AWT-EventQueue-0
07:11:48.959 InterfaceGlobalEvent (org.nlogo.app.interfacetab.InterfacePanel$$anon$1 (org.nlogo.window.SliderWidget)) AWT-EventQueue-0
07:11:48.959 InterfaceGlobalEvent (org.nlogo.app.interfacetab.InterfacePanel$$anon$1 (org.nlogo.window.SliderWidget)) AWT-EventQueue-0
07:11:48.959 PeriodicUpdateEvent (org.nlogo.app.App$$anon$4 (org.nlogo.window.GUIWorkspace)) AWT-EventQueue-0
07:11:48.837 InputBoxLoseFocusEvent (org.nlogo.window.ButtonWidget) AWT-EventQueue-0
07:11:48.758 InterfaceGlobalEvent (org.nlogo.app.interfacetab.InterfacePanel$$anon$1 (org.nlogo.window.SliderWidget)) AWT-EventQueue-0
07:11:48.758 InterfaceGlobalEvent (org.nlogo.app.interfacetab.InterfacePanel$$anon$1 (org.nlogo.window.SliderWidget)) AWT-EventQueue-0
07:11:48.758 PeriodicUpdateEvent (org.nlogo.app.App$$anon$4 (org.nlogo.window.GUIWorkspace)) AWT-EventQueue-0
07:11:48.558 InterfaceGlobalEvent (org.nlogo.app.interfacetab.InterfacePanel$$anon$1 (org.nlogo.window.SliderWidget)) AWT-EventQueue-0```
````

Comment: try running it with different values for (number) and tell us what the pattern is.

Comment: okay I updated my post with the error message. I'm not sure if there is any pattern I can see

Comment: The error message says "Dot 4 is not a centroid". The problem is in `face centroid who`, that is in "dot-context". So the who number refers to the dot. If you have a look at all who numbers (e.g. `aks turtles [show who]`), you will see that there is no centroit 4.

Comment: There is also a problem with how you set up the centroids, since the dots will be assigned multiple times to different centroid. You can see that when you use inside `move-centroid`: 
`let candidate-dots dots with [(who > [who] of myself and who <= (([who] of myself) + 3)) or (who <= (([who] of myself) - (number - 4)))] `
    `ask candidate-dots [set label [who] of myself]`
    `create-links-with candidate-dots `